# Can i make a node reference to some field but not the title field?

Tags: nodes

I have a salary content type and i want to reference the salary value from another content type.
Can i make a node reference to some field but not the title field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make node reference to a view 
In a case I added a title and an image in an auto-complete and it worked fine
you can check it by adding any field not a title

Comment: how can get fields values of referenced node?

Comment: you can reference to a view not a node. Make a new view and choose reference not page or block (inside the view make a new reference) and then you will find in node reference field attach to a view

Comment: i added a referenced views and i add the field that i want to be referenced.  
then i added a node reference field and chose the views that i created.  
but when a create a new reference the title of the referenced node appear not the value of field that in referenced views.
where is the problem? thanks for your helping

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed solution is good enough, but you may try this one:

1. create the reference using [Entity reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module
2. create new view mode and name it **referenced** for node bundles using [Entity view
   modes](http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode) module
3. in content type display setting page, use **Rendered entity** as
   display formatter and select referenced as rendering view mode
4. edit node's .tpl file and do what you want for those view mode